# Jquery code running multiple times on page load

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, click

I have the following code, this code runs when a person clicks a link. But I also need to load it initially when the person visits the page to load the default address. So after this code I have $('.viewmap').click();

The problem is when I do that the click action is ran for each link with the class viewmap. Is it possible to have this code run once with mapid having the default value of 0 so I can reuse this function for both default loading of the map and then if someone clicked one of the links with the viewmap class? Or do I have to create separate functions? One for the default load and one for the click action?

```
$('.viewmap').click(function() {

    var id = $('#id').text();
    var mapid = $(this).attr('title');

    $.ajax({
        cache:false,
        url:'path/to/script'
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {

            $('#currmap').gMap(
                    {
                        latitude   : data.lat,
                        longitude  : data.lon,
                        address    : data.address,
                        maptype    : 'ROADMAP',
                        zoom       : 8,
                        markers:[{
                                     latitude    : data.lat,
                                     longitude   : data.lon,
                                     address     : data.address,
                                     html        : data.display
                                 }]

                    }

            );

        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the processing code in it's own function. You can then call that directly on page load, and also when a click event happens on the element. Try this:

```
function updateMap() {
    var id = $('#id').text();
    var mapid = $(".viewmap").attr('title');

    $.ajax({
        cache:false,
        url:'path/to/script'
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {    
            $('#currmap').gMap({
                latitude   : data.lat,
                longitude  : data.lon,
                address    : data.address,
                maptype    : 'ROADMAP',
                zoom       : 8,
                markers:[{
                    latitude    : data.lat,
                    longitude   : data.lon,
                    address     : data.address,
                    html        : data.display
                }]
            });
        }
    });
}

updateMap();
$('.viewmap').click(updateMap);
```

This then avoids having to manually trigger the click event on the elements which is what is causing your problem.

Comment: what if the page contain lof of div having class `$('.viewmap')`

Comment: Then each click of a `.viewmap` element will call the function once.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.viewmap:first').click();
```

Comment: Though I accepted the other answer I wanted to mention the solution above works as well and out of the 2 the quickest to implement. But the second solution I can reuse the function for other things as well. Thanks for the help everyone!